# Php login (beginner)

Tags: php, authentication

```
...

if(isset($_POST['in'])){

    $username = $_POST['w_user'];

    $w_password = md5($_POST['w_password']);

    $mysql_password = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE password = '$w_password' and username= '$username'";



    $mysql_password_query = $connect->query($mysql_password);
```

// how to check username (from mysql ) equal to $username

```
    $info = $mysql_password_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if($info == $username){
...
```

//here i'm checking $info array but i need some string value

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and need to read the docs for [fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: Also, in addition to @MarcB 's comments, I'd suggest using a better hasing algorithm than `md5`. The hashing algorithm is weak and vulnerable to rainbow table attacks with today's available computing hardware.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are selecting one field. 
You need to access the first index of the array:

```
if($info[0] == $username){...}
```

Other things:

- Use prepared statement.
- `md5` is not appropriate for password.
- You can check the number of rows return rather than fetching the username value and compare.

Comment: if($info["username"] == $username)